# Invalid Argument in Float data type

Tags: sql-server

Argument data type float is invalid for argument 2 of format function.

```
select 'Purchase',Format(sum(case when Project='Dammam Central'   then  (Price)  end) ,'##,##0.#0') as [Dammam Central],
                  Format(sum(case when Project='Dammam East'   then  (Price)  end) ,'##,##0.#0') as [Dammam East],
                  Format(sum(case when Project='Hadeed FPH'   then  (Price)  end) ,'##,##0.#0') as [Hadeed FPH],
                  Format(sum(case when Project='Hadeed MTO'   then  (Price)  end) ,'##,##0.#0') as [Hadeed MTO],
                  Format(sum(case when Project='IBN Rushd'   then  (Price)  end) ,'##,##0.#0') as [IBN Rushd],
                  Format(sum(case when Project='Jeddah SMPT'   then  (Price)  end) ,'##,##0.#0') as [Jeddah SMPT],
                  Format(sum(case when Project='Jubail JCP'   then  (Price)  end) ,'##,##0.#0') as [Jubail JCP],
                  Format(sum(case when Project='Dammam Central'   then  (Price)  end),
                  sum(case when Project='Dammam East'   then  (Price)  end) +
                  sum(case when Project='Hadeed FPH'   then  (Price)  end) +
                  sum(case when Project='Hadeed MTO'   then  (Price)  end) +
                  sum(case when Project='IBN Rushd'   then  (Price)  end) +
                  sum(case when Project='Jeddah SMPT'   then  (Price)  end)+
                  sum(case when Project='Jubail JCP'   then  (Price)  end) ,'##,##0.#0') as [Total]
 from purchase
```

Comment: The row after `[Jubail JCP]` doesn't have a 2nd parameter. However, the better solution is don't use `FORMAT` (which is awfully slow) and do the formatting of your data in your presentation layer.

Comment: okay thanks. i will check

Comment: You could also greatly simplify the last column. Sum(case when Project in (...) then Price end)